# Feature idea: suggested questions tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

How about an additional tab on the questions screen "suggested".  This will give you unanswered questions that match the tags you have accepted answers for.

Answer (score 5):

What would be the difference between this and "Unanswered"->"My Tags"?

Comment: good point.  wasn't aware of the "Unanswered"->"My Tags".  the difference would be 'suggested' would be derived from the tags on your accepted answers.  the 'my tags' feature is probably close enough anyways.