# Status-* tags - moderator only?

Tags: support, tags, meta, moderator-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work)

I just tried to edit the tags of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7667/feature-idea-suggested-questions-tab) to add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag to it (since the feature is already present), but every time I submit the edit I get dumped back to the edit page again.  Is this a moderator only tag (i.e. only moderators can apply it? Does the same apply to the other [status](/questions/tagged/status) tags?

Comment: (the [2nd answer in that faq post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640) explains required / moderator tags in-depth)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Red tags (example, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)): moderator only.
- Strong outline tags (example, [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)): required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, moderator only. Jeff knows best, what is completed and what's not ;-)