# Marking questions as [status-completed]

Tags: discussion, meta, bug-reports, moderator-tags, feature-request-process

Is it OK for regular users such as myself to mark questions here on meta [status-completed], assuming that what they're asking about has actually been implemented?

There are a lot of questions asking about similar things, but frequently not all variations get marked completed. They may not even be dupes exactly, but are trying to address the same issue and are all effectively "completed" by one bug fix or feature roll-out.

I was going to tag one of these, but I'm not sure what the etiquette is about the official tags.

Comment: @Tim - so is it worth flagging or should I just leave it? (also, might as well post your response as an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: It's funny, because I actually had posted that as an answer, and the system auto-converted it to a comment due to the trivial answer filter, heh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You needn't worry about the etiquette, since you [can't add moderator-only tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/status-tags-moderator-only) anyway. If you try, you get a nice error message reminding you:

[image: moderator-only tag error message]

Usually when features are implemented, the devs do a pretty good job of retagging all of the related posts. But in the case where they overlook something, (after considering it some more) I don't think there's any reason you can't flag for moderation attention to ensure that it gets marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). After all, if they haven't yelled at Michael Mrozek yet for doing it (per his comment), then you don't have anything to worry about.

If you're going to flag though, and the question isn't enough of a duplicate to be closed as such, I would also recommend linking to an answer detailing how the feature was implemented for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I flag stuff regularly to add a mod-only tag and they haven't yelled at me yet, so it seems to be fine

Comment: Proof enough for me. Plus it's not as though it's flooding the mod queue, so I'm not sure why I was that concerned about it in the first place.

Comment: Retag requests are sometimes fulfilled by non-moderators, so I guess you may have to flag when they get done.