# Should I flag for moderators to add status tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags, meta, moderator-tags

Occasionally I see an old Meta post that has no status tag (like [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)), but from the answers it looks like the question is resolved.

Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/why-is-http-compression-of-data-not-enabled-on-so-or-sf should be [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) since the answers say HTTP compression actually is enabled.

Is it worth flagging these questions, or is that a waste of time?

Comment: I do see a steady trickle of mods adding these tags to very old posts most days, usually during less active times.  I imagine they might get annoyed if you filled up their queue with dozens of such flags every day though.

Comment: Related: [Marking questions as \[status-completed\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99175)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since moderators are the only people who can add status tags, this seems acceptable. I've done it a few times, with success. The benefit of any given individual status tag is pretty minimal, though, so you probably shouldn't do it too frequently.

Comment: Now that you're a CM would you still agree with the 'not too frequently'?

Comment: Yeah, I still think this is a good answer. If you come across a question in your regular travels that clearly deserves a status tag but doesn't have one, go ahead and flag. It's when people start actively hunting for flags to cast that they start to get into "doing it wrong" territory.

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and other status-* tags only apply to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions, and sometimes to [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions. They indicate that a request for action by a moderator or developer has been officially processed. They are irrelevant and generally not applied to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions, which are an open call for the community to participate.

Please do flag to add [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) to feature requests and bug reports that have been resolved. Other than that, it would be a waste of time. For example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11045/why-is-http-compression-of-data-not-enabled-on-so-or-sf doesn't really call for a status-* tag.

Comment: What about [meta-tag:retag-request]s? They are fairly status-related. Or are they incorrectly tagged as [meta-tag:discussion]?

Answer (score 5):

You can also vote to close the question as off-topic because it can no longer be reproduced. This is excellent for things that weren't changed on purpose but happened to go away as part of something bigger.

[image]