# Request for merging "tips and tricks" tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I was searching for tags about "tips and tricks" and found at least 5 tags, which seems redundant:

- <strike>342x [tips-and-tricks](/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) - *DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012"*</strike>
- <strike>62x [tricks](/questions/tagged/tricks) - *no wiki summary*</strike>
- <strike>19x [trick](/questions/tagged/trick) - *no wiki summary*</strike>
- <strike>6x [programming-tips](/questions/tagged/programming-tips) - *no wiki summary*</strike>
- <strike>24x [hints-and-tips](/questions/tagged/hints-and-tips) - *no wiki summary*</strike>

Maybe merging them could be a good idea?

Comment: Why not just clean them up? The ones with fewer questions should be easy enough to take care of.

Comment: @RudiVisser Done.

Comment: @Bart How did you do that? Have you edited 25 posts manualy?

Comment: @F.Hauri I took care of all the [trick] posts, yes. Removing the tag, editing them into shape. Or flagging them for deletion where necessary. The [programming-tips] ones must have been somebody else.

Comment: I've sorted out [tag:hints-and-tips]. Surprisingly most of the questions were already closed or actually helpful so only detagging was required.

Comment: Seems to be [status-completed]

Comment: @RichardTingle [Or maybe not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150244/206447)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These tags should all just be removed.  Probably a lot of the questions they're on should be closed as well, so please don't just remove them.  Vote to close the question they're on if it's a subjective "list of X" question.

Once the tags are removed from all questions, the tag itself and its wiki will be deleted from the system within 24 hours.  After that, low-reputation users will be blocked from re-creating the tags.

Answer (score 0):

- I would argue for removing [tricks](/questions/tagged/tricks), [trick](/questions/tagged/trick) and [hints-and-tip](/questions/tagged/hints-and-tip) - they do not seems to convey too much about a question / subject.
- Regarding [programming-tips](/questions/tagged/programming-tips) sounds to me like a valid tag, I would expect these questions to hold good programming practices.

  I am somewhat surprised that [tips-and-tricks](/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) that was flagged as "DO NOT USE" is still active. **Is there a way to block this tag from being used in the future**?

Comment: There is no other way to block the tag from being used other than to help in the process of cleaning it up. Same thing goes for the [homework] tag. I delete a couple of new ones on a daily basis.