# How do I make a call to add the status-completed tag?

Tags: support, meta

I raised this [question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/text-not-visible-when-adding-image) for a bug, I just noticed that bug was resolved, I tried to add the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, but it not allow me to add. Now how do I make a call to add the tag or will I leave it as it is.

Comment: I've added a [meta-tag:status-norepro] to the post.

Comment: @AlE. don't think it's a dupe, the other posts explain *what* are those tags, not how to request to apply them when needed.

Comment: Correct duplicate found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150241/152859

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Is it really worth re-opening and re-closing, though?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, better keep it as organized as possible in my opinion. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Agreed, decaying duplicates chains where each duplicate is almost the same but not quite; leading to the two ends of the chain having no relation to each other are a pet peeve of mine

Comment: @RichardTingle done! Actually on second thought best dupe isn't the end of the chain but one before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You flag the question for moderator attention; choose 'other' and request that the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag is added.