# It's hard to search for things like status-completed, which are meta tags, *outside* the tags

Tags: feature-request, support, meta

I was going to ask a question about how [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) should be handled in conjunction with accepting answers, as I couldn't find anything, but as I wrote the question, I finally got useful data in the Similar Questions panel to the right of [/questions/ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

So I decided to change my question to "why can't I do useful searches for these meta-meta-things?"

Why is it so hard to search for things related to status-completed (and other meta tags), ignoring the actual tag [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

- The regular search tool is useless for this purpose; searches like `status-completed -[status-completed]` return no results, and searches like `status-completed` (wrangle with it to get it to *not* turn it into a search for `[status-completed]`, such as by adding another keyword) just return a whole lot of [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions.
- The "Questions that may already have your answer" list that appears in the Ask Question page once you fill out the title are useless. (I suppose it uses the same sort of data source/technique as the regular search tool.)

However:

- The Similar Questions panel to the right of the Ask Question page, which appears once you start writing a question, *does* provide useful results. I guess it doesn't include the tags in what it searches. (It was there that I found things like [Should I flag for moderators to add status tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150241/should-i-flag-for-moderators-to-add-status-tags) and [Marking questions as [status-completed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99175/marking-questions-as-status-completed), which are what I had been looking for. And they demonstrate that tags like [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) and [meta-tags](/questions/tagged/meta-tags) can't be depended upon for search.)

So then: could the search tools be improved in some manner so that this style of search becomes possible? Perhaps by making `status-completed -[status-completed]` work, or by introducing some way of excluding tags from the search fields?

(It should of course be understood that mitigating this problem is the fact that it's really only the meta tags that will need to be searched in this way.)

Answer (score 4):

`"status-completed" -[status-completed]` seems to work:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22status-completed%22+-%5Bstatus-completed%5D

Comment: OK, so *that's* the trick... double quotes. :-/

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Yes, quotes prevent the automatic conversion to tag

Comment: Hang on... a search like `vim -[vim]` on the main site works, as does `"vim" -[vim]`. But one like `objective-c [objective-c]` gets interpreted as tags and thus gets no results (and `"objective-c" [objective-c]` works, as you indicated it would). So it seems like it's to do with the hyphen. That's not nice!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Only the top 50 or something tags get auto-converted, this has likely to do with the tag popularity

Comment: Argh. This gets more and more entangled! I had tried a couple of tags of each variety and that seemed to be the common factor...