# Status tags versus the tag limit

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta, moderator-tags

Moderators apply [status tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/status-tags-moderator-only), such as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), to questions on Meta when a bug/feature/request/etc. is resolved. But the number of tags is limited to 5.

So what happens if my question already has 5 tags? Should I stick to a maximum of 4 tags in case my question gets resolved?

Comment: Surely moderators will find a way out and delete the least relevant tag if there is a need to do so.

Comment: Surprised is has no been suggested before - I think those moderator tags should not count towards the 5 tags limit as they do not describe the question itself just its "status", kind of "meta tags".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: And now it has 5 tags. Uh-oh...

Comment: Yep but there's no status tags for discussion or support, only for bugs or feature requests. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Not counting toward the limit may anywhere from possible to quite hard. It really depends on the database design. Admittedly, I have not checked, but it's really easy to have designed the database such that the limit of 5 is hardcoded within the structure of the database. Overall, having status tags not count towards the limit sounds like one of those things which might be nice, but would cost developer time for something that has an adequate workaround (i.e. just remove a different tag) and which is relatively rare issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I stick to a maximum of 4 tags in case my question gets resolved?

No, you should not. Just add the relevant tags as you would do with your questions on other Stack Exchange sites.

> So what happens if my question already has 5 tags?

The moderator will remove a tag to add the one s/he needs. Keep in mind that the "status-*" tags are normally applied just to feature requests, and bug reports. Sometimes, they are applied to questions tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support), but that is rare.